# How to stop recursion in setInterval() . Javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Slideshow test</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<p id="demo"><p>

<script>
var Index = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

(Index <4) ? setInterval(slide,500):display(Index-1);


function slide() {
    var i;  
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
     Index++;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Index-1;
    x[Index-1].style.display = "block";    
}

function display(n) {
  x[n].style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to display a sequence of images by setInterval().In the end, there should display last image. 
Problem is after running, there is no image . I am sure the variable 'Index' still keep increasing by 1. I don't know why....

Comment: If you want to know how to stop the calling of `slide`, you should assign the return value of `setInterval` to a variable (e.g. `intervalHandler`) and do `clearInterval(intervalHandler)` when `Index` is equal to `x.length`. You can do this at the end of the `slide` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs `clearInterval` method to stop the `interval`. I've replaced your `images` with `divs` for demo purpose.

```js
var index = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

function displayNextSlide() {
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (i === index) {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  index++;
  if (index == x.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
displayNextSlide();
var interval = setInterval(displayNextSlide, 500)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
  .mySlides {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <h2 class="w3-center">Slideshow test</h2>

  <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <div class="mySlides" src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">1</div>
    <div class="mySlides" src="2.jpg" style="width:100%">2</div>
    <div class="mySlides" src="3.jpg" style="width:100%">3</div>
    <div class="mySlides" src="4.jpg" style="width:100%">4</div>
  </div>
```